# Python Ursina: No me funciona un botón

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando hacer un botón, que cuándo le des click una entidad se destruya, pero me da error y no sé como solucionarlo.

Este es el código que me da error:

```
b.on_click = robuxman.on_disable
b = Button(scale=(.5, .25), text="Presioname", texture="images.png")
robuxman = Entity(model = "quad", texture="imagen.jpg", position=(0,0,0), scale=(35,10,6))
```

Comment: Es una halago, pero no somos adivinos. No podemos resolver un error sin información.

Comment: y el error cual es?

Comment: Como que tu código está al reves. ¿No deberías inicializar primero?